# .Net Windows application not working in others machine

Tags: .net, windows

I have developed a tool/app using windows application (GUI) via Visual studio. This app I have build in Release mode and executed in my PC as well. But when I am trying to share with my colleagues it is giving a warning message as below:

> Smart Screen can't be reached at the moment

Check your internet connection. Microsoft Defender SmartScreen is unreachable and can't help you decide if this app is OK to run.~

Publisher: **UNKNOWN PUBLISHER**
APP :

A button as "Don't Run".
[image]

Comment: On all of the latest versions of Windows applications must be signed with an EV token without it Windows will declare that it is from an unknown origin and by default prevent it from running. Depending on your workplace security set-up you may be able to overcome this and then you'll be offered the option of run it anyway. EV tokens are registered at a known location that Microsoft uses to verify the source of an application

Comment: Obviously, this is a temporary problem since it is complaining of internet connectivity issues. Resolve the internet connectivity issue.

Comment: Hi Mike Nakis
There is no internet problem

Comment: Thanks ChrisBD , I will look further